# Kibana and OpenSearch incompatible versions

Tags: kibana, opensearch

I'm trying to integrate Kibana with my OpenSearch ( is it possible ? ). Unfortunately I get a version error.
Is there any way to use opensearch in kibana?

These are the versions I get via curl:

```
curl -k -u "admin:PASSWORD" "https://IP:9200/"
{
  "name" : "node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "he6gqhl2S-6dlVv6dyPOEA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.2",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "e505b10357c03ae8d26d675172402f2f2144ef0f",
    "build_date" : "2022-01-14T03:38:06.881862Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.10.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are very tightly coupled and aren't really supposed to work together, so I doubt they will (or it would be very brittle).

If you want to have Kibana, why not Elasticsearch under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use Kibana with Opensearch. The combo everyone uses now is:

- Elasticsearch + Kibana (free opensource)
- Opensearch + Opensearch Dashboard (provided by AWS - recommended for commercial).

So instead of integrating Kibana with my OpenSearch, you should use Opensearch Dashboard.

About function and ability, both elasticsearch/opensearch or kibana/opensearch-dashboard will look similar each other just a few syntax changes.